# Compute complex integral resulting from FT

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-transform

I obtain the following integral after doing a FT of a function

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi(x + i\xi)^2}dx$$

I am not sure how to evaluate it. I tried change of variable $y = x+ i\xi$. but what is the limit of this as $x \to + \infty$ or $-\infty$? I know the Gaussian integral but I cant see how it is useful for this

Help is much appreciated

note: $\xi$ is a real constant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may re-write the integral as:

$$ e^{\pi \xi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\pi x^2 - 2\pi i \xi x\right)\,dx.\tag{1}$$
Consider the function:
$$ J(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-\pi x^2-2\pi i \xi x)\,dx \tag{2}$$
and check through differentiation under the integral sign and integration by parts that it fulfills:
$$ J'(\xi) = -2\pi \xi\, J(\xi)\tag{3} $$
so:
$$ J(\xi) = K\cdot e^{-\pi \xi^2}\tag{4} $$
and since $J(0)=1$, $K=1$. By plugging in $(4)$ into $(1)$, it follows that the original integral just equals $\color{red}{\large 1}$ (it does not really depend on $\xi$).

Comment: Or simply use Cauchy's Integral Theorem. ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV: sure, but it is interesting to show how to avoid complex-analytic tools in some simple cases like this one.

Comment: Differentiation under the integral sign just reminds me of the formula I should use for the FT of the derivative, and the derivative of the Fourier transform.. we can find a differential equation satisfied by $f(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$, apply FT and get a differential equation satisfied by the FT of $f$, which is the one you obtained to get the result. thank you!

Comment: Jack, absolutely.  And in any case, it is always "cool" to have alternative ways to arrive at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

Upon enforcing the substitution $x\to x-i\xi$, we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2}\,dx=\int_{-\infty-i\xi}^{\infty-i\xi} e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx \tag 1$$

Using [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem), we assert that since $e^{-\pi z^2}$ is an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) then

$$\oint_C e^{-\pi z^2}\,dz=0 \tag 2$$

for any closed contour $C$.

Take $C$ as comprised of the line segments (i) from $-R$ to $R$, (ii) from $R$ to $R-i\xi$, (iii) from $R-i\xi$ to $-R-i\xi$, and (iv) from $-R-i\xi$ to $-R$.

It is easy to show that the contributions to the right-hand side of $(2)$ from (ii) and (iv) vanish as $R\to \infty$.  Therefore, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty-i\xi}^{\infty-i\xi} e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx \tag 3$$

Using $(3)$ in $(1)$ yields

> $$\begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2}\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx\\\\
> &=1
> \end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

In this note, we show that the contributions to the integral on the left-hand side of $(2)$ from integrations over the vertical strips approach zero.  To that end, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{\xi}e^{-\pi (\pm R+iy)^2}\,i\,dy\right| &  \le e^{-\pi (R^2-\xi^2)}\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: It might be useful to add that the contributions of the integrals along the vertical edges are $O(e^{-\pi R^2})$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @kobe Sure.  I thought that that was evident.  But I will add as a note.  -Mark